# Django Mixin method that affects composite class

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have the following simple classes:

```
class NumberMixin(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()

class RaceCar(models.Model, FancyMixin, ScaryMixin, NumberMixin):
    def common_logic():
        obj = RaceCar.objects.filter(name='fortytwo').first()
        obj.number = 42
    ...

class Athlete(models.Model, LotsOfStuffMixin, NumberMixin):
    def common_logic():
        obj = Athlete.objects.filter(name='fortytwo').first()
        obj.number = 42
    ...
```

Each class which is partially composed of `NumberMixin` will have a `common_logic()` which is almost identical.

If I want `common_logic()` to be used for any class that inherits from `NumberMixin`, is there any way I can put it in the `NumberMixin` class instead of having to copy-paste it into all of the other classes?

Comment: You can introduce a new level in your inheritance hierarchy. This new level will have two classes one that has 'common_logic' in his definition while the other does not.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the only difference in between the `common_logic` methods is the model. Therefore you could create a class method and use `cls`:

```
class NumberMixin(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()

    @classmethod
    def common_logic(cls):
        obj = cls.objects.filter(name='fortytwo').first()
        obj.number = 42
```